# Layout won't load after button click

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I'm trying to load a second layout after the click of a button but for some reason the application keeps crashing... I'm pretty sure I did everything right - but it's still failing for some reason after each time I click on the save button at the bottom of the screen.

P.S.

If any more information is needed please let me know. I'll be happy to provide it.

---

### JAVA

```
package com.example.linkingmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
}
public void saveButtonClicked(View v) {
    // do stuff
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(App2Activity.this, AppActivity.class);
    App2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);

   }

    }
```

---

### XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="User Settings:" />
    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Data Limit" />
    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="10MB" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        <TextView android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Unlimited Data" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Bandwidth Limit" />
    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="10kbs" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        <TextView android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Unlimited Bandwidth" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="WiFi Time Limit" />
    <TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Blocked Sites - [ex: www.xxx.com]" android:ems="10" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/saveButton" android:onClick="saveButtonClicked" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Save"     />
    </LinearLayout>
```

---

### LOGCAT

```
03-04 07:35:41.939: D/dalvikvm(944): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 7% free 2456K/2640K, paused 46ms, total 49ms
03-04 07:35:41.989: I/dalvikvm-heap(944): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.831MB for 3456016-byte allocation
03-04 07:35:42.049: D/dalvikvm(944): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 5828K/6016K, paused 58ms, total 59ms
03-04 07:35:42.139: D/dalvikvm(944): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 5828K/6016K, paused 8ms+16ms, total 90ms
03-04 07:35:42.799: D/libEGL(944): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-04 07:35:42.878: D/(944): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a155228, tid 944
03-04 07:35:42.959: D/libEGL(944): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-04 07:35:42.979: D/libEGL(944): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-04 07:35:43.099: W/EGL_emulation(944): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-04 07:35:43.119: D/OpenGLRenderer(944): Enabling debug mode 0
03-04 07:35:47.248: W/EGL_emulation(944): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-04 07:35:55.629: D/AndroidRuntime(944): Shutting down VM
03-04 07:35:55.671: W/dalvikvm(944): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method saveButtonClicked(View) in the activity class com.example.linkingmanager.App2Activity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'saveButton'
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: saveButtonClicked [class android.view.View]
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
03-04 07:35:55.709: E/AndroidRuntime(944):  ... 11 more
03-04 07:35:58.489: I/Process(944): Sending signal. PID: 944 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Something is not correct in saveButtonClicked you are referring to super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can fix this (apologies if I'm a noob)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

from your method :

```
public void saveButtonClicked(View v)
```

Thanks

Comment: I deleted it - and it's still crashing - only this time before I click save. (Just when the layout loads) : (


Updated Java:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nqWw8hncYKEv8K_tF3tvNjkaj4IUcbtVDfZrBYxbwqk/edit?usp=sharing


Updated LogCat:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Dc0iKW8ej3XeOcXRyaYc3p-NPQdQ6oX-yPKCPLtBMNg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Any suggestions? (I know it's probably something super simple)

Comment: After removing those two things I'm getting an error stating: 

The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){}) App2Activity.java /LinkingManager/src/com/example/linkingmanager line 16 Java Problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you show only the part of xml. Where is the button with click listener declaration? My guess - names of the method in xml and in code are different.

BTW, don't call super.onCreate(Bundle) in no other place than onCreate().

Comment: The entire file is attached.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be declaring your button in your activity and then calling onClickListner to it.

```
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(App2Activity.this,AppActivity.class);
                    App2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
    });
```

and remove `android:onClick="saveButtonClicked"` from xml

otherwise go with solution given by Prateek Sharma

Comment: ALso try cleaning your project once.

Comment: Now it's crashing before I click save. 

Updated Java:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/15HaC7s5d8rYR0zNFklR65FU3wxCgntBGnxxnS7sEzd0/edit?usp=sharing

Updated XML:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IvV5YGGv11pWsum1gpIiZeRfPrUe6ThVpYRmNilkELk/edit?usp=sharing

Updated LogCat:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ErHPC_LdXSoiWJ3G3a0QbM2rQ41SVM-LjCdKMA-9lbE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public class App2Activity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton)
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(App2Activity.this, AppActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
    }
```

---

It will be much easier to do it this way.

Comment: check if you have this  -> import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: I was really hoping that would work - but it just caused the crash to happen when the layout first loads instead of when I click save.

Most Recent LogCat: 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IvV5YGGv11pWsum1gpIiZeRfPrUe6ThVpYRmNilkELk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you resolved this error -- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement? Can you post your recent code as well?